# Sending IP address to an email in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ip-address, actionmailer

I want to be able to send a new user's ip address to my admin account when a new user signs up. I have:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => '"Admin" <support@mysite.com>'

  def registration_confirmation(user)
    @user = user #needed in order to have access to user variables
    def client_ip
      @client_ip = request.remote_ip
    end
    mail(:to => "#{user.name} <#{user.email}>", :subject => "Welcome to MySite").deliver!
    mail(:to => '"Admin" <support@mysite.com>', 
           :subject => "New Member",
           :body => "New member #{user.name} with email #{user.email} and ip: #{@client_ip} has just signed up!",
           :content_type => "text/html")
  end

end
```

I'm getting the error:
NameError in UsersController#create
undefined local variable or method `request' for #

users_controller.rb

```
def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      UserMailer.registration_confirmation(@user).deliver
      sign_in @user
        redirect_to @user
    else
        render 'new' 
    end
  end
```

Comment: The request method is available in the controller.  If you need it in the mailer you will need to pass it as an arg.

Comment: I updated by adding the argument (see above). I no longer get any errors, but in the email, the ip address is coming up blank.

Comment: can you add the controller code where you are calling registration_confirmation?  That is where you have access to the request method which has access to the ip.  You should probably pass it in to the registration_confirmation method as a parameter.

Comment: Added the controller code. Can you show me an example of what you mean? I am a bit new to rails. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      UserMailer.registration_confirmation(@user, request.remote_ip).deliver
      sign_in @user
        redirect_to @user
    else
        render 'new' 
    end
end


def registration_confirmation(user, client_ip = '0.0.0.0')
  @user = user #needed in order to have access to user variables
  mail(:to => "#{user.name} <#{user.email}>", :subject => "Welcome to MySite").deliver!
  mail(:to => '"Admin" <support@mysite.com>', 
       :subject => "New Member",
       :body => "New member #{user.name} with email #{user.email} and ip: #{client_ip} has just signed up!",
       :content_type => "text/html")
end
```

You only have access to the request object in the controller/view.  So you need to pass the value along to the mailer if that is where you want to have access to it.

Comment: Worked! Just currious, what is the reason you added '0.0.0.0' instead of just client_ip alone? Is it because you can't pass a blank value?

Comment: That is a default value, so that if you need to send an email manually or something, you can just call: registration_confirmation(user) and the email will be set to 0.0.0.0  which is sometimes used for localhost